# How to run tests for all commits during a rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have a feature branch with plenty of commits.

```
A---B---C     master
 \
  \-B'---C'---D'...---Z'  feature
```

I am working on `feature` but another developer has created commits `B` and `C`. Now I want to rebase `feature` on commit `C`, but I and/or automerge introduced errors during the rebase. My project has very good test coverage and I can run the tests from console using `ant rebuild test`, and now I want git to tell me which commit is the first commit that breaks my test so I can fix that commit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While you are on branch `feature` execute:

```bash
git rebase --interactive --exec "ant rebuild test" C
```

This will cause git to start again on commit C, replay your work on top and it will run your tests after each commit it applies during replay phase.

Hopefully your ant task will have a non-zero exit code if your tests fail. In this case git will stop as soon as the tests fail. You are immediately in the right position to amend you commit so that the tests will be happy again. After you have amended just execute `git rebase --continue` as usual and git will continue to check all you commits.

Comment: And if all the tests pass, it would be as if the `-exec` flag wasn't there, right? I mean that you will not be prompted with a message for the success of `-exec`...?

Comment: @hal: It is a long time ago, but I believe so.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the [OP yankee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327301/yankee)'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560897/6309), Git 2.5+ will provide a more robust `git rebase --interactive --exec` experience, especially in case of a *failed* exec.
Actually, see the **new `--reschedule-failed-exec` of Git 2.21** in the last part of this answer.

See [commit b12d3e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b12d3e904dc6deba7885d8528538de13e28128dd) [22 May 2015], and [commit 1d968ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d968ca69809ffb7b9105a4785aa0bc3b37b1434) [22 May 2015] by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a6be52e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6be52e239df4d4a469a5324273f43a0695fe95d), 01 Jun 2015)</sup>

> The '`exec`' command is sending the current commit to `stopped-sha`, which is supposed to contain the original commit (before rebase).
> As a result, if an '`exec`' command fails, the next '`git rebase --continue`' will send the current commit as  to the post-rewrite hook.

---

The full documentation:

> ### `rebase -i`: fix `post-rewrite` hook with failed `exec` command

> Usually, when '`git rebase`' stops before completing the rebase, it is to give the user an opportunity to edit a commit (e.g. with the '`edit`'
> command).
> In such cases, '`git rebase`' leaves the sha1 of the commit being rewritten in `"$state_dir"/stopped-sha`, and subsequent '`git rebase --continue`' will call the `post-rewrite` hook with this sha1 as `<old-sha1>` argument to the `post-rewrite` hook.
>
> The case of '`git rebase`' stopping because of a failed '`exec`' command is different: **it gives the opportunity to the user to examine or fix the
> failure, but does not stop saying "here's a commit to edit, use
> `--continue` when you're done"**.
> So, there's no reason to call the `post-rewrite` hook for 'exec' commands.
> If the user did rewrite the commit, it would be with '`git commit --amend`' which already called the `post-rewrite` hook.
>
> Fix the behavior to:
>
> - **leave no `stopped-sha` file in case of failed `exec` command**,
> - and teach '`git rebase --continue`' to skip `record_in_rewritten` if
>   no `stopped-sha` file is found.

---

To facilitate managing failed exec directives associated to a rebase, Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) introduces `--reschedule-failed-exec`, with "`git rebase -i`", which learned to re-execute a command given with '`exec`' to run after it failed the last time.

See [commit 81ef8ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81ef8ee75d5f348d3c71ff633d13d302124e1a5e), [commit 969de3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/969de3ff0e01282cc061892f47b5f04b22de76af), [commit d421afa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d421afa0c66ec6bbd15602d534f77546c516f2a5) (10 Dec 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d9d9ab0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9d9ab0876e5ba82996852e7033b2fb29c970914), 29 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase`: introduce `--reschedule-failed-exec`

> A common use case for the `--exec` option is to verify that each commit
> in a topic branch compiles cleanly, via `git rebase -x make <base>`.
>
> However, when an `exec` in such a rebase fails, it is not re-scheduled, which in this instance is not particularly helpful.
>
> Let's offer a flag to reschedule failed `exec` commands.
>
> Based on an idea by **Paul Morelle**.

The [`git rebase` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d421afa0c66ec6bbd15602d534f77546c516f2a5/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L504-L507) now includes:

> ```
> --reschedule-failed-exec::
> --no-reschedule-failed-exec::
> ```
>
> Automatically reschedule `exec` commands that failed.
> This only makes sense in interactive mode (or when an `--exec` option was provided).

And:

> `rebase`: introduce a shortcut for `--reschedule-failed-exec`
>
> It is a bit cumbersome to write out the `--reschedule-failed-exec` option before `-x <cmd>` all the time; let's introduce a convenient option to do both at the same time: `-y <cmd>`.

Note: the first committed in reverted in See [commit e11ff89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e11ff8975bedc0aae82632c3cb72578c3d7fc0b2) (06 Feb 2019), and [commit 81ef8ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81ef8ee75d5f348d3c71ff633d13d302124e1a5e) (10 Dec 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b966813](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b966813e716504252ea26a635db21aa628e3dbd8), 09 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### Revert "rebase: introduce a shortcut for --reschedule-failed-exec"

> This patch was contributed only as a tentative "we could introduce a
> convenient short option if we do not want to change the default behavior
> in the long run" patch, opening the discussion whether other people
> agree with deprecating the current behavior in favor of the rescheduling
> behavior.
>
> But the consensus on the Git mailing list was that it would make sense to show a warning in the near future, and flip the default `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec` to reschedule failed `exec` commands by default.
>
> So let's back out that patch that added the `-y` short option that we
> agreed was not necessary or desirable.

---

Also in Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019): "`git rebase -x $cmd`" did not reject multi-line command, even though the command is incapable of handling such a command.
It now is rejected upfront.

See [commit c762aad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c762aada1ab3a2c428c462e0e6964d9f37107da7) (29 Jan 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 96e6547](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96e6547c2e4c137222c01582b52c0c974a02fd63), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase -x`: sanity check command

> If the user gives an empty argument to `--exec` then git creates a todo
> list that it cannot parse. The rebase starts to run before erroring out
> with:
>
> ```
> error: missing arguments for exec
> error: invalid line 2: exec
> You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'.
> Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.
> ```
>
> Instead check for empty commands before starting the rebase.
>
> Also check that the command does not contain any newlines as the todo-list format is unable to cope with multiline commands.
> Note that this changes the behavior, before this change one could do:
>
> ```
> git rebase --exec='echo one
> exec echo two'
> ```

And it would insert two exec lines in the `todo` list, now it will error out.

---

With Git 2.23, the configuration variable `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec` should be
effective only while running an interactive rebase and should not affect anything when running an non-interactive one, which was not the case.
This has been corrected.

See [commit 906b639](https://github.com/git/git/commit/906b63942ac7f0ff904228b03d5dbe1edc59f0fe) (01 Jul 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 64096fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64096fb41d36cf0e9808c9d15ae46ec364e5c800), 11 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase --am`: ignore `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec`

> The `exec` command is specific to the interactive backend, therefore it
> does not make sense for non-interactive rebases to heed that config
> setting.
>
> We still want to error out if a non-interactive rebase is started with
> `--reschedule-failed-exec`, of course.
>
> Reported by **Vas Sudanagunta** via [commit 969de3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/969de3ff0e0#commitcomment-33257187).

---

"[`git rebase --[no-]reschedule-failed-exec`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0377ac98dcf797d4711d2f0757ce49171ee4bb04/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L616t)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---reschedule-failed-exec))</sup> did not work well with its configuration variable, which has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit e5b32bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5b32bffd1ddec64a1d1f593764d05841dd715e5), [commit cd663df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd663df710f0fd082cef006333804e7e416b2680) (09 Apr 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0377ac9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0377ac98dcf797d4711d2f0757ce49171ee4bb04), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5b32bffd1ddec64a1d1f593764d05841dd715e5): don't override --no-reschedule-failed-exec with config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a bug in how `--no-reschedule-failed-exec` interacts with rebase.rescheduleFailedExec=true being set in the config.
> Before this change the `--no-reschedule-failed-exec` config option would be overridden by the config.
>
> This bug happened because of the particulars of how "rebase" works v.s.
> most other git commands when it comes to parsing options and config:
>
> When we read the config and parse the CLI options we correctly prefer the `--no-reschedule-failed-exec` option over `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec=true` in the config.
> So far so good.
>
> However the `--reschedule-failed-exec` option doesn't take effect when the rebase starts (we'd just create a ".git/rebase-merge/reschedule-failed-exec" file if it was true).
> It only takes effect when the exec command fails, at which point we'll reschedule the failed "exec" command.
>
> Since we only wrote out the positive ".git/rebase-merge/reschedule-failed-exec" under `--reschedule-failed-exec`, but nothing with `--no-reschedule-failed-exec` we'll forget that we asked not to reschedule failed "exec", and would happily re-read the config and see that `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec=true` is set.
>
> So the config will effectively override the user having explicitly disabled the option on the command-line.
>
> Even more confusingly: Since rebase accepts different options based on its state there wasn't even a way to get around this with "[`rebase --continue --no-reschedule-failed-exec`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5b32bffd1ddec64a1d1f593764d05841dd715e5/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L247)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---continue))</sup> (but you could of course set the config with "`rebase -c ...`").
>
> I think the least bad way out of this is to declare that for such options and config whatever we decide at the beginning of the rebase goes.
> So we'll now always create either a "reschedule-failed-exec" or a "no-reschedule-failed-exec file at the start, not just the former if we decided we wanted the feature.
>
> With this new worldview you can no longer change the setting once a rebase has started except by manually removing the state files discussed above.
> I think making it work like that is the the least confusing thing we can do.
>
> In the future we might want to learn to change the setting in the middle by combining "`--edit-todo`" with "`--[no-]reschedule-failed-exec`", we currently don't support combining those options, or any other way to change the state in the middle of the rebase short of manually editing the files in "`.git/rebase-merge/*`".
>
> The bug being fixed here originally came about because of a combination of the behavior of the code added in [d421afa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d421afa0c66ec6bbd15602d534f77546c516f2a5) ("`rebase`: introduce `--reschedule-failed-exec`", 2018-12-10, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9d9ab0876e5ba82996852e7033b2fb29c970914) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a)) and the addition of the config variable in [969de3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/969de3ff0e01282cc061892f47b5f04b22de76af) ("`rebase`: add a config option to default to `--reschedule-failed-exec`", 2018-12-10, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9d9ab0876e5ba82996852e7033b2fb29c970914) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a)).

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5b32bffd1ddec64a1d1f593764d05841dd715e5/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L625-L632):

> Even though this option applies once a rebase is started, it's set for
> the whole rebase at the start based on either the
> `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec` configuration (see [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)
> or "`CONFIGURATION`" below) or whether this option is
> provided.
> Otherwise an explicit `--no-reschedule-failed-exec` at the
> start would be overridden by the presence of
> `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec=true` configuration.

---

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024) explains the persistent nature of the `--reschedule-failed-exec` flag from the user standpoint:

See [commit 25aec06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25aec063265f9efbe542f1a15e6f634b715d305d) (04 Jan 2024) by [Illia Bobyr (`ilya-bobyr`)](https://github.com/ilya-bobyr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a57da6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a57da6bfee2d9cdc2d25a8dd22942334666dd56b), 16 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25aec063265f9efbe542f1a15e6f634b715d305d): clarify --reschedule-failed-exec default
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Illia Bobyr</sup>

> Documentation should mention the default behavior.
>
> It is better to explain the persistent nature of the `--reschedule-failed-exec` flag from the user standpoint, rather than from the implementation standpoint.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25aec063265f9efbe542f1a15e6f634b715d305d/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L623-L632):

> This option applies once a rebase is started. It is preserved for the whole
> rebase based on, in order, the command line option provided to the initial `git rebase`, the `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec` configuration (see
> [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) or "CONFIGURATION" below), or it defaults to false.
>
> Recording this option for the whole rebase is a convenience feature. Otherwise
> an explicit `--no-reschedule-failed-exec` at the start would be overridden by
> the presence of a `rebase.rescheduleFailedExec=true` configuration when `git rebase --continue` is invoked.
> Currently, you cannot pass
> `--[no-]reschedule-failed-exec` to `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 4):

Introduced in [Git 2.9](https://github.com/blog/2188-git-2-9-has-been-released), you can now execute a command for each commit using the `-x` option without having to also add `--interactive`.

Instead of running `git rebase -i --exec "cmd1 && cmd2 && ..."`, you can now run `git rebase -x "cmd1 && cmd2 && ..."`.

Comment: But... `-i` is the same as `--interactive` and that is what your examples contain...?

Comment: @yankee My answer definitely does not make it clear what I was trying to convey. I'll update it shortly, but basically I wanted to convey that you can use `git rebase -x 'make test'` as a shortcut for executing a command against each commit.