# Effective way to locally compile each commit

Tags: git

I often want to split my newly written code into multiple commits. I also want to verify that each commit compiles.

Is there any efficient way to locally ensure that each commit compiles without having to stash, compile and stash pop through each one?

Comment: Do you want that when you check-in your code locally it compiles automatically locally?

Comment: Yes, without the uncommitted changes

Comment: Once you've done all the commits you could do an interactive rebase with `--exec` to verify that they all build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run tests for all commits during a rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560896/how-to-run-tests-for-all-commits-during-a-rebase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a **pre-commit** Git Hook to make sure all of the code that you are trying to commit can actually compile.

There are some samples given in the *.git/hooks* folder of your repository.

More information about Git Hooks can be found [over here](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).